# CLion only shows type of result in debugger, not actual value

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clion

So I have this problem in a lot of places including watches, but it's especially annoying for evaulate expression. Basically, CLion successfully evaulates the expression, figures out that it gives back a result, shows the type of the result, but doesn't actually show me the value. Is there some magic command I'm missing to actually see the value? I can see if I switch to lldb instead of gdb, but lldb has it's own set of problems, including expression evaluation not working at all in most contexts. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens when there is some error evaluating the expression. CLion doesn't indicate there is an error in gdb mode other than the red squiggle (in lldb mode, it does show some errors, sometimes). Correcting the error made the value show up next to the type of the result